# Changing default evaluation context inside an action object

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Is there any XForms object which I could use to override default evaluation context inside an action object? We have xforms:group in body part but do we have any in xforms:action? It would simplify code where I often use the same Nodeset as a base element I'm operating on

I would like to receive such code:

```
<xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
  <?xf:context? ref="instance('main')/d:Content/d:Attachment[index('repeat-id')]"> <!-- ?? -->
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:FileName" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Description" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:MimeType" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Size" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Location" value="..." />
  </?xf:context?>
</xf:action>
```

so I wouldn't have to repeat the whole path all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is `context`. As of XForms 1.1, the `context` attribute is only available officially on the `insert` and `delete` actions, but some implementations already support it on all actions, and it is [scheduled for inclusion in XForms 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/@context_everywhere).

```
<xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" context="instance('main')/d:Content/d:Attachment[index('repeat-id')]">
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:FileName" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Description" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:MimeType" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Size" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Location" value="..." />
</xf:action>
```

Note that `ref` is, as far as I know, not officially allowed on `action`.

There is a difference between `ref` and `context` as planned for the upcoming XForms 2:

- `context` only changes the XPath evaluation context
- `ref` usually has other effects, such as binding a control, or specifying the destination of a value (`setvalue`), etc.

In XForms 1.1, `context` on `insert` unfortunately also can indicate the insertion point, but XForms 2 plans to improve on that and deprecate that use of `context`.

Comment: I've checked this solution as well and Orbeon supports context attribute same way as ref attribute. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can have `ref` attribute to the `<xforms:action>`tag. And you can apply this to `<xforms:trigger>` and `<xforms:group>` tags also.

With this, you will give the context for the statements within the tag.

I have tried this which works fine.

So your code should look something like:

```
<xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate" ref="instance('main')/d:Content/d:Attachment[index('repeat-id')]"> 
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:FileName" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Description" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:MimeType" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Size" value="..." />
    <xf:setvalue ref="d:Location" value="..." />
  </?xf:context?>
</xf:action>
```

Comment: I will check this out tomorrow morning but by now I haven't found ref attribute in [XForms 1.1 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#action-action) so wondering where did it come from - is it maybe Orbeon extension?

Comment: I couldn't wait till morning, and have already checked and it really works... Thank you very much for this answer. I feel that I need to try any intuitive solution regardless the reference :-)

Comment: thanks for confirming it. Also please upvote if you accept the answer so that it can be easily accessed by others.

Comment: I've tried but I can select only one response as an answer and I have to select ebruchez one as to be more complete though both are correct. sorry.

Comment: i agree. No problem at all :)